# How do I create a total blank page without any header and footer?

Tags: theming, nodes, 6

I am using Drupal 6 and I am stuck in a situation where I need to create a blank page without any header footer which comes as a part of your theme when you create a new page in Drupal.

I have searched lot on this problem  :

1. [Drupal link that I used to get solution](https://drupal.org/node/376596), but not helped.
2. [Create a content type to get blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509146/new-content-type-with-completely-blankbody-of-node-only-output-theme-files)  solution also not able to solve my problem.

Can any one help me to create blank page without any theme components.

I also read about creating a hook but I am not able to create any hooks.

How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you want this for every page on your site or for just a specific path.  Or paths?

Comment: I want for single page and not for every page.

Comment: What specific page?  That will dictate the name of the page template you will need to create.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy of `page.tpl.php` in your theme and rename it according to the [Template Suggestions for Drupal 6](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089642).

Your theme should be in a directory like `site/all/themes` or `sites/default/themes`.

So if you wanted a custom `page.tpl.php` for http://yoursite.com/path/to/override, your file name will end up being something like `page--path-to-override.tpl.php`.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 6 you likely want to override `page.tpl.php` for your theme; and remove the "header" and "footer" HTML elements.

See the source here:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21page.tpl.php/6

This file outputs your page's full HTML structure. So you can tweak it for content type (using a theme *suggestion*) as need be.

In Drupal 7 to get do the same thing you would tweak `html.tpl.php`.

Comment: how I can tweak page.tpl.php ?

Comment: with a text editor, or an IDE. Please review the online documentation https://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7