# How do I create a PHP page?

Tags: theming, 6

I need to create a web page in Drupal 6. The site has multiple PHP pages under different themes. For example, inside opt/mycompanyWeb/web/sites/all/themes/custom/MyCompanyInterior there are a bunch of pages such as page-node-50.tpl.php and page-node-608.tpl.php.

I have figured out to create a static page via the *Add content* menu, but I haven't figured out how to get Drupal to display a page I create in that directory. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Does this help: [How to create a total blank page without any header and footer in Drupal 6](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/105819/1908)?

Comment: At first glance, unfortunately no. I don't want a blank page or a new theme. Just a new php page with the same theme. All I really need is a way to copy an existing page with a backing php template to a new page with a different node, which I could then modify.

Comment: Although one ugly hack could be to copy the view-source html, then somehow check in the page template for the id if the page in question, and just display the content, similar to the solution for the blank page. But I just don't want to go there. There are already a lot of pages like this. I just need to figure the switch or toggle that generate the page.

Comment: Sounds like there is a pattern to follow in those other pages. It also sounds poorly built with theme files being used to do the job of modules or other tools. If you work out the file name convention and read through template.php you can probably create more like the ones that exist.